# mimic Android tab styling?

Tags: android, android-layout

Could anyone suggest the best way I would mimmic the styling of the android tabs? e.g these tabs...

[image]

I've basically got a RelativeLayout with a Textview inside and I want to make my RelativeLayout look like the android tabs. How would I design this? What's the best way to go about this?